# Exporting a function from KVM_main.c getting error: implicit declaration of function

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kvm

I'm trying to export a function from KVM_main.c.  I can successfully compile the kernel but when I call the function I get an error that leads me to believe it's not being exported correctly.  Below is the code I'm using to export it.

```
MODULE_AUTHOR("Qumranet");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
LIST_HEAD(vm_list);
.
.<other code>
.
struct list_head * kvm_get_vm_list(void)
{
    return &vm_list;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kvm_get_vm_list);
```

I believe I'm exporting it correctly as I've worked with this before and was able to export it.  For whatever reason I can't get it to work this time.  Is there a way that I can check the exports on that file to see if it is correctly exported?  Do I have to import something to access it?  Below is the code I'm trying to access it with.

```
lvm_list = kvm_get_vm_list();
```

Below is the error I'm getting.

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘kvm_get_vm_list’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function's prototype needs to be added to the appropriate header file as well.

```
struct list_head * kvm_get_vm_list(void);
```

What you're experiencing is a *compiler error*, which means your C file doesn't know about the existence of the function in question.

The `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macro only specifies that the symbol be exported, so it can be *linked* against.